# IReport incompatibility with Java 8

Tags: java

I have installed Java 8 in my PC (actually, its the only JDK installed) and I have iReport version 5.1.0.

Once I run iReport nothing happened. It did not run at all.

I think there is an incompatibility with the 2 technologies. I have searched and found out in a a certain forum that even the latest version of iReport doesn't support Java 8.

How true is this? If this is true, how long will it take for iReport new release to support Java 8? Is there any alternative tools for me to use in reporting?

I am using Netbeans 8.0.

Comment: Can you post links to the forums?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about specific support for a third party product. You should contact the creators instead and ask them for more information.

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/824715/ireport-compatibility-java8

This is the link where I read about the incompatibility. Do you think that the support will be released soon?

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
window->Preferences->java-compiler
```

Change compiler compliance level: to 1.7,1.6 etc which is compatible with report.